# Excel VBA - Find values in a range and store adjacent cell in variable

Tags: vba, excel

I have code that is now able to take a range of values and find the highest, next highest, and so on values and paste them as variables to a different workbook.

What I am now trying to do is find the string (in this case, name) adjacent to a specific value, and paste that string in the other workbook.

I know what I need to use to do that, but I am not getting it right.

The section between the comment lines is where the issue is, as everything else works on its own.

```
Dim sipRng As Range: Set sipRng = [G1]
Dim rng As Range: Set rng = [C4:C16]
Dim firstVal As Double, secondVal As Double, thirdVal As Double, fourthVal As Double, cel As Range
Dim var As Variant, iSheet As Integer, iRow As Long, iRowL As Long

For Each cel In sipRng
    If InStr(cel.Value, "Inbound AHT") > 0 Or InStr(cel.Value, "Valid Quality Count") > 0 Or InStr(cel.Value, "Valid Quality %") > 0 Then
        firstVal = Application.Small(rng, 1)
        secondVal = Application.Small(rng, 2)
        thirdVal = Application.Small(rng, 3)
        fourthVal = Application.Small(rng, 4)
    ElseIf InStr(cel.Value, "Outbound Calls Made") > 0 Or InStr(cel.Value, "FCR %") > 0 Or InStr(cel.Value, "FLR %") > 0 Or InStr(cel.Value, "Corrected CSAT Average") > 0 Then
        firstVal = Application.Large(rng, 1)
        secondVal = Application.Large(rng, 2)
        thirdVal = Application.Large(rng, 3)
        fourthVal = Application.Large(rng, 4)
    End If
Next cel

'''''''''''''''''
iRowL = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
For iRow = 1 To iRowL
    If Not IsEmpty(Cells(iRow, 1)) Then
        For iSheet = ActiveSheet.Index + 1 To Worksheets.Count
            var = Application.Match(Cells(iRow, 2).Value, Worksheets(iSheet).Columns(2), 0)
        Debug.Print var
        Next iSheet
    End If
Next iRow
''''''''''''''

nngr2.Activate
Range("B4") = firstVal
Range("B11") = secondVal
Range("B9") = thirdVal
Range("B6") = fourthVal
```

This is what I start with

[image]

This is the goal, only instead of the values, I want the name (in this case, letter)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a starting point, this loads a 2 dimensional array with the values and pastes those values in E4 of the active sheet:

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim rng As Range
Dim arr(1 To 4, 1 To 2)

Set rng = [C4:C16]

For i = 1 To 4
    arr(i, 2) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Large(rng, i)
    arr(i, 1) = rng.Cells(Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(arr(i, 2), rng, 0)).Offset(, -1).Value
Next i

nngr2.Range("B4").value = arr(1,1)
nngr2.Range("B11").value = arr(2,1)
nngr2.Range("B9").value = arr(3,1)
nngr2.Range("B6").value = arr(4,1)

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Your next step is likely to use the `Range.Sort` [MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840646.aspx) which will identify the highest, next highest, and so on.

Comment: @PeterT that would be the best way if the data can be sorted, I have seen where the bosses do not like the data messed with in any way.

Comment: Very true, and in that case I'd copy the data to a temporary/unused range (or worksheet) and sort the copy to find the ordered data. Or at least that's one approach. The OP needs to specify any additional constraints he may have and we'll lend a hand as needed :)

Comment: @ScottCraner All, I updated my question with images so it makes more sense. The first image is the data I start out with, the second is the goal, only I want the name in col B not the value. The values are not being sorted, they are being entered as seeds (think of it is a head-to-head contest)

Comment: @ScottCraner It works up to the nngr2.Range("B4").value = arr(1,1) line.  I then get a 438 run time error, "object doesn't support this property or method".
nngr2 is a workbook declared earlier in the script.  It is not active when the code you provided runs, so I tried adding nngr2.Activate just above this part, but that does not help.

Comment: I did a debug.print for each variable, and the correct name shows up.  So the only issue is the very last part

Comment: Then you need to add the sheet: `nngr2.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B4").value = arr(1,1)`

Comment: Ah yes I was just about to respond, dumbing it down worked too: `Range("B4") = arr(1, 1)`